# Glitchy sound effects

Tags: glitch, effect, plugins

What's everyone's favourite way of making glitchy sound effects and manipulating dialogue in a glitch-style way?

I'm quite partial to just chopping up the waveform into tiny segments and stitching them together in interesting ways... Using Ableton's grain delay and beat repeat is quite a good method to get some more fluid control over them too.

Any other great tools?

Answer (score 3):

Max/MSP. I make custom patches for all my Post-Digital, Glitch aesthetics.

Also, try opening up audio in a text editor and edit the text.

Comment: I know, i love Max too but it's good to venture out and get some other takes that you may not have thought of. Max for Live is a fantastic combination though. 

I tried the text editor trick but the results i got were just comparable to digital noise

Comment: You have to be subtle in your approach when it comes to the text editing! I have been working with text now for just over a year to create all forms of glitch art; Audio, Film, Photography.. The more you explore it, the more you come to understand just how editing text affects the media you open.. Try opening different file types; MP3, Wav, AiFF etc. and alter things very subtly. For example copy a huge chunk of the audio and paste it over and over again, or re-arrange the text without adding or subtracting from it.. Just make sure you don't touch the header and footer

Comment: Ahh, okay, i was deleting chunks and typing in random strings of letters. Tried subtly altering in Windows notepad today, but no dice. I'll try it on Mac later

Comment: I gave this text idea a shot.  wav files would not open after opening and saving in notepad (even without altering them), so make sure you make duplicates and only try this trick with the backups and not the originals.  Great idea btw!

Comment: I use TextEdit on the mac and it works perfectly for me, every time..

Answer (score 1):

Buffer Override is indeed awesome, as per @Serge, but I also love the SupaTrigga plugin and GleetchLab.

Comment: @NoiseJockey, what's the install method for Buffer Override? I've dumped both the mono and stereo files into the VST folder but Soundminer isn't seeing them. (In the finder they come up as Unix Executable Files)

Comment: @Jay, that's super weird. Mine installed as AU on my Mac, shows up just fine in Logic and Pro Tools, but I installed it a long time ago. Hmm. Shoot me an email if you wanna follow up.

Comment: I got them running no problem by just dragging the dll files into my vstplugins folder too

Answer (score 1):

I would add dBlueGlitch:  http://illformed.org/plugins/glitch/

It is somewhat tamer than the Smartelectronix plugins. Meaning it's easier to control the amount of every effect that you apply, so you no longer have to rely on randomness.

Answer (score 1):

In Pro Tools, flip on the elastic audio mode to either polyphonic or monophonic.  Set the track to warp and add breakpoints at random.  Stretch out the waveform.  Don't be afraid of the waveform turning red (I believe this indicates potential for artefacts) - in fact, embrace this.  Go crazy with it.  When you're done, for further glitchiness, chop up the clip at random, turn on shuffle mode, and start moving things around.  Try duplicating a few small sections as well for interesting stutter effets.

I also second the idea to use dblue Glitch & buffer override.  You might also try Image-Line's Gross Beat.

Comment: Here's another couple ideas - throw effect/dialogue into a beat slicer (image-line's slicex, for example) or sample (Kontakt will also let you slice up your sample) and trigger it with midi.  Some slicers will allow you to add various articulations (such as pitch/volume randomization) or you could try adding some pitching effects.  If my affection for Image-Line products is not yet evident, I would also suggest the Fruity Loops Granulizer as an awesome way of getting glitchy effects.

Answer (score 1):

All of the above, but perhaps a lesser known but interesting glitch box is the [Lost Technology VST](http://rekkerd.org/ce00423/docs/userdoc.html), especially if your host can randomize all the parameters. I also love to combine it with the [Atlantis filter delay VST](http://www.kvraudio.com/product/atlantis_by_jeremy_evers). [GrainCube](http://designingsound.org/2010/05/graincube-a-free-reaktor-instrument-for-granular-sound-manipulation/) is also good fun.

Answer (score 1):

for iPad check out Glitch Breaks

Answer (score 0):

dfx Buffer Override, SmartElectronix LiveCut.

Comment: Buffer override looks pretty useful, and free, too! Even better!

Answer (score 0):

IZotope's Stutter Edit is pretty good for glitchy.

Answer (score 0):

Thought i would jump back to this one as i have just been playing with a tool that has given me insane audio! 'Obelisk' by Artificial Audio.

http://www.artificialaudio.com/

I usually just play with the spectral gating but i just used the delay and feedback it offers on my whole mix and it chundered out some amazing glitch.. It sounds a lot like the breakdown section of Alva Noto's 'Uni Deform'

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KrC4jwBld0w

Comment: That youtube link isn't the best but listen to the last 20 seconds of it..